# unresolved external '__fastcall Dbtables::TQuery::TQuery(Classes::TComponent*)

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm using BDS 2006 and going to use TQuery in a console application. I disable the option "use dynamic library" and "use Runtime packages", because I want to export the application to another pc. 
if I compile the source, I get a linker Error:
" unresolved external '__fastcall Dbtables::TQuery::TQuery(Classes::TComponent*) referenced ..."

below my code.
do I need another header files and if yes which one?

thanks

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <DBTables.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop
TQuery *Query1;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Query1 = new TQuery(NULL);
   //do some operation with Query1
   system ("pause");
   delete Query1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to add paths to the library, not include directives. The code is compiled successfully, but it cannot be linked (this is a linker error).

Comment: I already add the paths $(DBS)\include\vcl and ..\lib, .. into the library. I don't know which path fails. (DbTables path is alreay add).

Comment: You don't just add the paths, you have to add the library name as well.

Comment: do you mean :    $(BDS)\include\vcl\DBTables.hpp?  schould I add this in option->linker->library path ?

Comment: No that's header file. Somewhere there must be a library that contains the code you are missing. That library needs to be added to your link step.

Comment: I copies the DBTables.pas in my Projectdirectory, and it works. thanks for your help